# Sort map by value

Tags: scala

I have `List[(String,String)]` and I need to sort them by the 2nd value and return a map

I have done the following:

```
val newMap = list.sortBy(_._2).foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String]) {
      (map, key) ⇒ map + (key._1 → key._2)
    }
```

list is a `List[(String,String)]`

However the returnning map isn't sorted!!

Comment: I think you should state why you need to return a `Map` and what sense of it being sorted you care about. For example; do you subsequently wish to add extra key-value pairs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default `Map` implementations are hash-based and they do not preserve order. Instead use `scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap`:

```
val newMap = list.sortBy(_._2).foldLeft(new LinkedHashMap[String, String]) {
    (map, key) => map += (key._1 -> key._2)
    map
}
```

As suggested by *@Rex Kerr*, `scala.collection.immutable.ListMap` might be a better choice for target type:

```
val newMap = list.sortBy(_._2).foldLeft(new ListMap[String, String]) {
    (map, key) => map + (key._1 -> key._2)
}
```

Or (once again full credits should go to *@Rex Kerr*):

```
val newMap = new ListMap() ++ list.sortBy(_._2)
```

However what do you really want to achieve? Looks like you might be choosing wrong data structure...

Comment: I disagree with this answer because it is misleading: you are returning a mutable structure which **is not sorted at alll**. It is simply *traversable in insertion order*

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: I think this is exactly what OP asks (based on sample code) - have a `Map` from `key` -> `value` but with entries sorted by `value`. However let OP decide which answer is correct or clarify. BTW I haven't downvoted your answer in return, to be clear ;-).

Comment: The entries are not "sorted" - they are traversable in a predictable order. This is not the same thing

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: well, they are sorted in the first step (`sortBy(_._2)`). But true, the returned collection can be modified afterwards to violate "*sorted*" contract.

Comment: If you use `immutable.ListMap` the distinction between "in insertion order" and "sorted" goes away.

Comment: Could you maybe `ListMap() ++ list.sortBy(_._2)` instead of the giant slow fold?

Comment: @RexKerr: haven't thought about it, genius :-). Yes, `foldLeft` is ver bad in this scenario as it creates a whole bunch of intermediate immutable maps.

Comment: Thanks @Rex Kerr &Tomasz Nurkiewicz.It works. However,is there anyway i can sort the list with case "insensitive" !!

Comment: @Echo: `list.sortBy(_._2.toUpperCase)`. And for the future - this is a new question rather than a comment.

Comment: Thanks... actually it was very naive question as I didn't think b4 I ask .... Actually how did I dare to ask it ! Thanks again and sorry for such question.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption from your question (which is not 100% clear): *you wish to have a `Map[A, B]` which is sorted according to `B`*

This is not possible; the scala sorted map is `SortedMap[A, B]` and this has to be sorted according to some ordering on the type `A`.

If all you want is a traversable sequence of pairs `(A, B)` according to `B`, then you have no need for a `Map` and the solution:

```
list sortBy (_._2)
```

...will suffice. If you wish to have a `Map`, then *Tomasz*'s answer looks enticing - but it is misleading. The map is *not sorted*; it is traversable in a known order (the order of insertion). This is **not the same thing** - subsequent additions to the Map will appear at the end (from a traversal perspective) regardless of what the value is. So I think you need to ask yourself a question: *what am I trying to do?*

If you care about traversing a sequence of pairs according to the second elements, you don't need a Map at all.

Comment: I have clarified what it was that I was assuming the OP is trying to do (i.e. create a `SortedMap[A, B]` which is sorted according to `B`) and then explain why this is impossible

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as:

```
val input = List((1,1), (3,4), (20,19), (2,2))
val output = input.sortBy(_._2).toMap
```

output is:

Map(1->1, 2->2, 3->4, 20->19)